# 3/16 ID x 5/16 OD beer lines

Tags: kegging, serving, tubing

I recently found a good deal online for food-grade beverage lines. I guess I only paid attention to the inner diameter measurements (3/16") to make sure it would fit with my existing barbed nipples and other adapters. Now that I've received my shipment, I noticed that it's much thinner than my existing lines. Turns out, my old ones are 7/16" outer diameter, while my new ones are 5/16".

Other than the increased likelihood of a pinched or kinked line, is there any reason I should avoid using these new lines?

Edit: here is the link to the product [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E6BCXQ8), and a screenshot in case the product link breaks in the future.
[image: Screenshot of details from Amazon.com]
Product Description: 
`ATP Vinyl-Flex PVC NSF 61 tubing is suitable for general low-pressure industrial applications for the conveyance of liquids and semi solids. It also complies with FDA regulations and is NSF 61 compliant for use in potable water and food and beverage applications. Although it is not primarily intended for use in higher pressure applications it does provide good chemical resistance is lightweight flexible phthalate free and economically priced. 55 psi working pressure at 70 degrees F. Meets FDA requirements. USP class VI rated materials. NSF 61 certified. RoHS compliant, reach, prop 65, ASTMF930-03, EN-71, PAHS. Applications: beverage dispensing, drain, potable water, laboratory, low pressure air, distilled water transfer and light vacuum.`

Comment: Any idea what it's made of? If not, what does it feel like? Is it rubbery and very flexible and either clear or opaque? Or is it slightly more rigid, less flexible and translucent? Also, is there braiding inside the plastic?

Comment: The product you linked to seems perfectly fine. Despite being thinner than your old line it's still rated for 55 PSI (which you should't come anywhere close to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  ID really all that matters with respect to line-length resistance and system tuning.  The OD does not matter, though it does make me question what type of material the tubing is … which would also affect line-length resistance…?